# Spring boot test configuration not being picked

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I am writing an integration test for my application, and want to use a custom webmvc configuration for my tests

I have three classes in my base package com.marco.nutri:

- Application(which is annotated with @SpringBootApplication)
- MvcConfig(@Configuration and @EnableWebMVC)
- SecurityConfig(@Configuration and @EnableWebSecurity)

My test is in the package br.com.marco.nutri.integration.auth:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes={Application.class, WebMvcTestConfiguration.class, SecurityConfig.class})
public class ITSignup {

    //Test code

}
```

I have a test config class in the package com.marco.nutri.integration:

```
@TestConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcTestConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    //Some configuration
}
```

But when I run my test, the MvcConfig.class is picked instead of WebMvcTestConfiguration.class

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can annotate your test configuration with `@Profile("test")` and your real one with `@Profile("production")`

and in your properties file put the property `spring.profiles.active=production` and in your test class put `@Profile("test")`. So when your application starts it will use "production" class and when test stars it will use "test" class.

from documentation

> Unlike regular @Configuration classes the use of @TestConfiguration
>   does not prevent auto-detection of @SpringBootConfiguration.
>
> Unlike a nested @Configuration class which would be used instead of a
>   your application’s primary configuration, a nested @TestConfiguration
>   class will be used in addition to your application’s primary
>   configuration.

Comment: but when I remove the Configuration from my production class it picks the class with TestConfiguration

Comment: how do you know that class with TestConfiguration is not picked at all..do you use a break point or print something?

Comment: I just asking because it would be a little bit tricky having the two configuration class runs because the @TestConfiguration will not replace the production class. Both of them will be working together.

Comment: If you want the two classes to replace each other, you can go with the proposed solution in my answer.